# On Form Submit trigger for simple code, but two forms linked to Google Sheets spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Issue:

I have a simple action that is required every time a new entry is added to my Google Sheets "Sales Form Reponses" page. The code for running it manually when I know this is needed, works perfectly well, and simply adds a new row to the sheet "Sales Data Clean", and copies all the formulas from the previous row. This is necessary because it adds some fields of information to the form entries.

```
function addRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sales Data Clean'), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

I am trying to use a trigger to make Google Sheets run this function whenever a new form entry is submitted.

Problem:

I have two forms linked to the overall Google Sheets document. The other sheet affected is called "Stock Form Responses", and the trigger won't allow to specify that the function AddRow should ONLY run if the Sales Form has a new entry. How do I do this? Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use e.range.getSheet() to figure out which sheet was being written to and thus which form just submitted

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response. Forgive me, but where on earth do I put that in order to make it run only on one form?

Comment: What is the name of the sheet for that form?

Comment: The form I want to trigger my function AddRow, is linked to the sheet "Sales Form Responses".

Answer (score 1):

```
function addRow(e) {
  const ash = e.range.getSheet(); 
  if{ash.getName()=='Sales Form Responses'){
    //Put your code in here
  }
}
```

Inspite of what @Nazia said the best answer is to attach the code to the spreadsheet and use e.values or e.namedValues instead of getLastRow() because if you get multiple submissions in quick succession that last row may the wrong one.

Comment: Apologies. I am brand new to Stack Overflow. I have no idea what points are or how to give them.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add script on your sales form instead and modify the sheet from there.

#### Code:

```
function addRow() {
  // sheet ID found in URL between /d/ and /edit
  var ssId = '1EkC7D3AbYsOoEtI3OsngCtfmhYJNPfMquIoObeTtZWM'; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sales Data Clean');

  var lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var range = sh.getRange(lRow, 1, 1, lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

#### Trigger:

[image: trigger1]
[image: trigger2]

#### Output:

[image: output]

- Last row was duplicated on "Sales Data Clean" sheet
- Will trigger every time that specific form (where your script is added) is submitted.

Comment: Why is it better to add to add the script on the form?

Comment: It's better not to use last row at all. It's better to get the event object on the spreadsheet and use e.namedValues or e.values.  If you get multiple submission from the same form the last row may not be the appropriate selection.  I think your wrong.  But if you wish to think that way it's okay with me.

Comment: I thought of a scenario where a multiple people submits the form almost at the same time and might have some problem with the script coping up with those edits. An edge case I believe and I do agree on your 2nd point that getting the event object is better. Going to modify the answer and rephrase my opening statement. Thanks @Cooper.